# html offline storage ~10MB cross-browser solution

Tags: javascript, html

I am dealing with a large application that needs to store a lot of meta data locally. Our size estimate right now is around 10 MB. Some HTML5 browsers have a 5 MB limit of the localstorage. Is there a more generic way of getting around the size problem without making user install some external DB (mongoDB etc..).

I also read that some browsers allow control on the size of localstorage, but not all. The solution needs to be cross-browser and the user should not have to do anything extra to make it work.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information but a solution which imposes to keep 10MB in local storage is suspect. The right direction is probably very different. For big data, you should use a server.

Comment: @dystroy the data is for a web app, entire rendering is done on the client side. and getting this data from the server every on every click might be sort of a performance hit, even with the caches in place.

Comment: With AJAX you don't have to send data on "every click". I have big applications which the users run for hours in their browser, no need to store the data in local storage. BTW loading the data from localStorage at every click wouldn't be efficient, it's better to keep it in JS objects.

Comment: You can’t store more data locally than the browser limit. Maybe you can hack your way into flash to do so, but it wouldn’t be reliable. You need to think of other ways of communicating data, via ajax or webSockets.

Comment: @dystroy as of today, the data is available in JS itself as globals and all the js files get downloaded from the server on demand and the required data is available in the browser space. But the sheer number of js files themselves are too large for this. and I was planning on making a meta file which has a blob of data, and a small js file which could query the required data of it. can you point me to some resources i could look up for handling similar cases.

Comment: @vvb Why are you so determined to (ab)use the localStorage? 10MB is a very large amount of data for a web application. It seems to me your application has a design flaw.

Comment: @Bart I am not :) Just exploring different approaches. and trying to see what might fit better. yes, I agree 10MB is a very large amount of data. The application itself if client heavy and the html is created on the client side. The 10MB is a theoretical worst case, assuming all functions get executed on the UI, which wouldn't happen. But it is still bad. Among other things, we have a lot of strings per widget/object_class which need to be available on the client for validating data received from the server. I am working on optimising/re-writing these aspects of the application.

Comment: Can't you write the app in a way that it uses as much space as is available, and where it isn't it calculates the data on the fly and will simply be slower? A typical memory-CPU trade off...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago. I ended up using indexeddb. Except for safari all current desktop browsers support it (http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb). Indexeddb gives you two apis: a synchronous and an asynchronous. The asynchronous api is the one most browser implement - which pretty fast ends up in a callback hell. In chrome and IE the indexeddb can even be used in webworkers (unfortunately not in FF). This way i was able to start the needed replication algorithm in the background.